# Meteor debugging and showing alerts, logs and messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am new to Meteor and I'm still trying to understand how a few things work. To have a better understanding of the language and the workflow, using alerts and printing messages to the console is a great idea. But I'm stuck on a few things

I wonder if the is a simple and default way to print messages to the console. For example, when I submit a form I can't make an alert to work and I can't see the the browser's console message I printed.

How can I do this kind of thing? Maybe printing messages to the system console where the server is running? Any further advise on how to use console, showing messages and alerts?

Comment: If you're using chrome for form submits if you want to console log you can use `preserve log checkbox` option to preserver the log

Comment: great answer. this was really helped. but do you know a way to show the logs on the system console?

Comment: no, I don't know any other ways. I'm also looking for good answer on this question

Comment: I'm having a problem with this. I set a callback to the `Collection.insert` method. If I try to `console.log('Test')` prints nothing. But if I `console.log(id)` with the returned id, it prints the ID in the console. If I use a variable instead of a string it also fails. It seems we can't rely on this method? What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would basically use `console.log()` to print logs to the console in javascript, that is basically what this function stands for.

If you do not see any results in the chrome console while expecting it, it can be for a few reasons:

- Your `console.log()` is not reached when executing your code. Make sure it is not in the wrong conditional scope

Example:

```
if (false)
  console.log('print me!'); // this desperate log will never see the light of day
else
  console.log('No, print me!'); // this one always will
```

- Your `console.log()` is ran on server side, therefore its output will be printed on your server logs, usually the terminal window you have on the side running meteor

Example:

```
if (Meteor.isServer)
  console.log('I\'m on the server!'); // this log will print on the server console
if (Meteor.isClient)
  console.log('I\'m on the client!'); // this log will print on the chrome console
console.log('I\'m omnipresent'); // this log will print on both
```

- If you have an error mentionning `undefined` popping up, the variable you are trying to print has not yet been defined. Make sure your variable is set before printing it

Example:

```
> var real_friend = "Bobby";
> console.log(real_friend);
"Bobby"
> console.log(imaginary_friend);
Error: 'imaginary_friend' is undefined.
```